# Mysql return different result from workbench and python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a `SQL` ran in python and workbench and both of them return different result. I believe the main cause is because I used `@variable` in `SQL`. Any workaround to make it returns same result? Here is my `SQL` and python code. Basically, the logic of the `SQL` is to rank the food in each supermarket and return the first 10 food (example only). In workbench, the counter is `1,2,3,4...` while in python they return `1` which doesn't do the counting. How can I prevent it? Thanks!

```
Code:
    cnx= mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = f'''SELECT supermarket, food, counter
            FROM (
            SELECT supermarket, food, 
                @counter:=IF(@supermarket_id= supermarket, @counter+1,1) as counter, 
                @supermarket_id:= supermarket
            FROM supermkt_data 
            order by supermarket, food) tmp
            WHERE counter<= 10;
            '''
    log.info(query)
    cursor.execute(query)
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    result = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: How are you fetching the result in python?

Comment: where are you initializing `@counter` and `@supermarket_id`  in both cases. Are you using a MySQL version with window functions?

Comment: @Nick H, updated the code. simply by cursor.fetchall()

Comment: @danblack I didn't. How can I initialize them?

Comment: [SET @count=0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: @danblack seems it doesnt work, In python, the cursor has no cache to do the counting